# How to implement percentage increase data from API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this problem where I need to fetch data from API and calculate the percentage increase within a certain number of days. Here's the code below...

```
function Card() {

  const [newEnrollments, setNewEnrollments] = useState("");
  
  const getNewEnrollments = async () => {
   // API call
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getNewEnrollments();   
  }, []);

  // data returned from API
  // { "new_enrollments": 12248 }  

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="card1">
        <div className="user">
          <HowToRegRoundedIcon className="icon" />
        </div>
        <div className="card-info">
          <h3>NEW ENROLLMENTS</h3>
          <h4>450</h4>
          <p>
            <BorderLinearProgress variant="determinate" value={90} />
            <span> 90% Increase in 90 Days</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

I want to be able to change the hard-coded values in h4(as the value from API), the progress bar, and the span value within 90 days. such that as more data is being updated the values dynamically changes and also the percentage increase.

Comment: Which part specifically are you asking for help with?

Comment: The percentage difference is `the difference between them divided by their average multiplied by 100`. You also need to keep track of average here

Comment: At some stage you're going to need to store the values somewhere permanently. Is it your API you're access or a public one? If it's yours your server should be doing that work for you. If not [look into localStorage as a solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Or you could build your own little API with Express that you access but which accesses the public API for you, and stores the data in JSON. Lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then

```
<h4>{data_returned_from_api["new_enrollments"]}</h4>
```

and

```
<span> {(data_returned_from_api["new_enrollments"] / old_data["new_enrollments"]) * 100}% Increase in 90 Days</span>
```

should do the trick. You should probably also add some try-catch-statements so that it doesn't crash if the data is missing.

Edit: Obviously, you need to be able to get hold of both the new value and the old value in order to use them. If you don't have both those values, then it is impossible.

Comment: Where's `old_data` coming from?

Comment: No idea. I assumed he already had that data. If he doesn't (and can't get it either), then it is impossible to solve the problem.